# I can't understand the crash logs of Swift without specific line showed in project

Tags: ios, swift, crash, widget, ios14

It seems it's the problem with the iOS14 widget, but I can't figure out where caused this problem, I clicked open in the project of the Xcode organizer, but it just showed me the thread, and I can't read this Log as well. How do you use this log file to understand the problem that the user encounters and caused crash? Is it possible to get the value of some variables that may cause the crash?

```
Hardware Model:      iPhone13,2
Process:             ItemProgressWigetExtension [41770]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F7971BB4-A593-4C01-99F2-580CD7C55CB7/Reborn.app/PlugIns/ItemProgressWigetExtension.appex/ItemProgressWigetExtension
Version:             45 (1.4.0)
AppVariant:          1:iPhone13,2:14
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2021-07-04 15:31:24.7283 +0800
Launch Time:         2021-07-04 15:31:24.5655 +0800
OS Version:          iPhone OS 14.4.2 (18D70)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    1.42.03
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  1

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1a765986c __exceptionPreprocess + 220 (NSException.m:199)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1bc672c50 objc_exception_throw + 60 (objc-exception.mm:565)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1a756095c -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 144 (NSObject.m:146)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x1a765c438 ___forwarding___ + 1444 (NSForwarding.m:3597)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x1a765e740 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 96
5   ExtensionKit                    0x1abbd5a44 -[EXExtensionContextImplementation _willPerformHostCallback:] + 192 (EXExtensionContext.m:541)
6   ExtensionKit                    0x1abbd83b4 __112-[EXConcreteExtensionContextVendor _beginRequestWithExtensionItems:listenerEndpoint:withContextUUID:completion:]_block_invoke + 972 (EXConcreteExtensionContextVendor.m:259)
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x1a724c24c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32 (init.c:1454)
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x1a724ddb0 _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:559)
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x1a725510c _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 580 (inline_internal.h:2548)
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x1a7255c5c _dispatch_lane_invoke + 408 (queue.c:3862)
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x1a725fd78 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 708 (queue.c:6601)
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1f3105814 _pthread_wqthread + 276 (pthread.c:2211)
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1f310c76c start_wqthread + 8

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d55852d0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d5584660 mach_msg + 76 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a75d4c30 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 380 (CFRunLoop.c:2641)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a75cec14 __CFRunLoopRun + 1216 (CFRunLoop.c:2974)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a75ce21c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3242)
5   Foundation                      0x00000001a887ddf0 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 232 (NSRunLoop.m:374)
6   Foundation                      0x00000001a88b16bc -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 92 (NSRunLoop.m:399)
7   libxpc.dylib                    0x00000001f3134c2c _xpc_objc_main + 688 (main.m:265)
8   libxpc.dylib                    0x00000001f3136f48 xpc_main + 180 (init.c:1206)
9   Foundation                      0x00000001a88b3a5c -[NSXPCListener resume] + 340 (NSXPCListener.m:448)
10  PlugInKit                       0x00000001d7daf960 -[PKService run] + 424 (PKService.m:186)
11  PlugInKit                       0x00000001d7daf588 +[PKService main] + 576 (PKService.m:115)
12  PlugInKit                       0x00000001d7dafd78 +[PKService _defaultRun:arguments:] + 24 (PKService.m:233)
13  ExtensionKit                    0x00000001abbe5c5c EXExtensionMain + 84 (EXExtensionMain.m:23)
14  Foundation                      0x00000001a8a02c70 NSExtensionMain + 200 (NSExtensionMain.m:13)
15  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001a728e6b0 start + 4

Thread 1 name:
Thread 1 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d55a9414 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f3104b50 pthread_kill + 272 (pthread.c:1392)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001b0a87b74 abort + 104 (abort.c:110)
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001bc778cf8 abort_message + 132 (abort_message.cpp:76)
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001bc769e4c demangling_terminate_handler() + 308 (cxa_default_handlers.cpp:67)
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001bc672f64 _objc_terminate() + 144 (objc-exception.mm:701)
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001bc7780e0 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 20 (cxa_handlers.cpp:59)
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001bc77806c std::terminate() + 44 (cxa_handlers.cpp:88)
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a724ddc4 _dispatch_client_callout + 40 (object.m:562)
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a725510c _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 580 (inline_internal.h:2548)
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a7255c5c _dispatch_lane_invoke + 408 (queue.c:3862)
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a725fd78 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 708 (queue.c:6601)
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f3105814 _pthread_wqthread + 276 (pthread.c:2211)
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f310c76c start_wqthread + 8

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f310c764 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f310c764 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 1 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x000000016d165e90   x5: 0x000000016d166440   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000000000600
    x8: 0x00000000000005b9   x9: 0x64e717f677a7f145  x10: 0x0000000000000002  x11: 0x0000000000000003
   x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x0000000000000001  x14: 0x0000000000000010  x15: 0x0000000000000052
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x000000016d167000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x000000000000260b  x21: 0x000000016d1670e0  x22: 0x000000020a540380  x23: 0x0000000000000000
   x24: 0x0000000000000114  x25: 0x000000016d1670e0  x26: 0x0000000281088640  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x0000000000000000   fp: 0x000000016d1663a0   lr: 0x00000001f3104b50
    sp: 0x000000016d166380   pc: 0x00000001d55a9414 cpsr: 0x40001000
   esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault
```

Comment: Looking at the backtrace, it looks like the widget framework tried to call `EXExtensionContextImplementation _willPerformHostCallback` and that method wasn't found.  This is in Apple's code.  Google reveals other have seen this crash in WidgetKit.  If you are seeing this crash in your analytics you can either ignore it or you could open a developer tech support issue with Apple, but it is going to be difficult if you can't come up with a [MCVE] for them